# Microsoft Graph API for Education: error listing user schools

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm trying to retrieve the `educationShool` list of an `educationUser` from Microsoft Graph [per the API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationuser-list-schools?view=graph-rest-1.0):

I am getting this error:

> Error message: The request URI is not valid. Since the segment
>   'memberOf' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in
>   the request URI or it must be followed by an function or action that
>   can be bound to it otherwise all intermediate segments must refer to a
>   single resource.

I have reproduced this issue in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/), if I try to send this request, I get the same error:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/me/schools
```

If I try to list the Classes (I think it should be a very similar scenario), it works ok:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/me/classes
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the API?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this and it looks like there may be a bug here. While that gets investigated, I can confirm that it works properly in the `/beta` release:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/me/schools
```

I'd suggest using `/beta` for this particular call if possible.

**Update:** This issue has been resolved and `education/{users}/schools` should now be working in both v1.0 and Beta versions.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your quick response. I have tried with the beta endpoint and it works fine. So I will use the beta endpoint until this bug gets resolved.

If it helps, I have found the same issue with this request:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes/class-uuuid/schools

I get the same error with v1.0 endpoint, and it works as expected with the beta endpoint.